# ORDER BY and GROUP BY together?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with sales data....here is the simplified version:

TABLE 'sales'

```
sale_no    PRIMARY KEY, INT
sku        INT (Any integer between 1-200000, is NOT unique in this table)
is_shipped ENUM('n','y')    'n' = NO, 'y' = YES
```

I need to select all sales which are not shipped (is_shipped = 'n') and show the sales with the SAME sku on a given web page. Something like this....?

```
SELECT * FROM sales
WHERE is_shipped = 'n'
GROUP BY sku (??)
ORDER BY sku
```

The above query needs to be modified so that only the sales with the same SKU are returned in the order of the SKU. For example, I need to show ALL unshipped sales for sku = 40 on a given page, iterating through all SKUs....any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `WHERE is_shipped = 'n' AND sku = 40`

Comment: When generating a specific page, do you know what SKU you want to present?

Comment: No.. the sku is not known....the page iterates through each sku as the sales are marked shipped. So the query needs to pull all unshipped orders for the smallest sku...

Comment: Remove `GROUP BY sku` from your current query, it'll show all unshipped orders from smallest sku to highest sku.

Comment: If you want to check for the smallest sku, you could make of use MySQL's aggregate [`MIN()`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-min/) function.

Comment: This is not what I meant! I need to show sales for a given sku on a webpage....all the sales containing that sku. The user will then mark all those sales as shipped...the page will reload the the new SET of sales with the next lowest sku will show up....on every reload....I DO NOT know the sku...the query needs to determine that.

Answer (score 2):

why are you order and group by, 
if you want all records from min sku value to max sku value than just order by your query

```
SELECT * FROM sales
WHERE is_shipped = 'n'
order by sku Asc
```

Comment: Have you tried your query? Is it showing list from min to max?

Comment: This is not what I meant! I need to show only ONE sku at a time...all sales containing that sku on the webpage. The user will then mark all those sales as shipped...the page will reload the the new set of sales with the same sku will show up....this time the next higher sku....

Comment: if you know sku than you can add sku=number in where condition. if you don't than select MIN(sku) for minimum sku value.